# Ralink Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, ralink

My Bluetooth is not working in Ubuntu 13.04. I am unable to turn it on and also, Bluetooth icon doesn't show up in the top bar.

I asked about this on #ubuntu IRC and they said that I am missing the proprietary drivers for it. There is nothing under **Additional Drivers** in **Software and Updates**

Bluetooth does work '**Try Ubuntu mode**' when I boot Ubuntu from DVD/USB.

How can I get the required drivers?

Answer (score 5):

If your Ralink Bluetooth devices is a RT3290, then you can follow this instructions:

1. Download this .zip archive from public folder:

   http://downloads.zotac.com/mediadrivers/mb/download/NB087_Ubuntu.zip
2. Unzip it to any directory, `cd $PATH-OF-YOUR-DOWNLOAD/NB087_Ubuntu/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/` and make bluetooth module:

   ```
   sudo make
   sudo mkdir /etc/Wireless/RT3290
   ```

   ...then copy necessary files in specified directory like this:

   ```
   sudo cp rtbth.ko /etc/Wireless/RT3290/
   cd $PATH-OF-YOUR-DOWNLOAD/NB087_Ubuntu/
   sudo cp rtbt.bin /etc/Wireless/RT3290/ ; sudo chmod +x /etc/Wireless/RT3290/rtbt.bin
   sudo cp 49rtbt /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/
   ```
3. Create startup script like this:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/init/bluetooth.sh ; sudo chmod +x /etc/init/bluetooth.sh
   ```

   ...past this into editor field and save:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   insmod /etc/Wireless/RT3290/rtbth.ko
   mknod /dev/rtbth c 192 0
   /etc/Wireless/RT3290/rtbt.bin
   exit 0
   ```

   ..then edit your `/etc/rc.local` (do this with sudo) and add line `/etc/init/bluetooth.sh` before `exit 0` line. This must look like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -e
   /etc/init/bluetooth
   exit 0
   ```
4. Test script by running and seek for errors:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init/bluetooth.sh
   ```

   Please do not forget to give execution flags and also for `rtbt.bin`.
5. Re-login or reboot machine and look for bluetooth applet in your taskbar

This is a typical scenario for installing Ralink 3290 Bluetooth Drivers, but this special version works for 13.04 based Ubuntu kernels. Look for this article http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2115570 for typical bluetooth driver installing.

Comment: I don't see the reason why set 777 to rtbt.bin, nor any of the files. They are only supposed to be executed by root, nor any other user, care to elaborate why not using `chmod +x`?

Comment: Oh, you right. Please disregard 777 permissions. Only necesary need to use `chmod +x`. Sorry for this I am so newbe in this question.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer for such a bizarre procedure.  Kudos.

Comment: i cnot find file rtbth.ko ?? help

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing compilation errors, try [downloading the package with source code](https://launchpad.net/~barracuda72/+archive/ralink/+files/rtbth-dkms_3.9.3-0ubuntu1~ppa3.tar.gz) and compiling + installing it manually. To do this open a shell where you downloaded the source, unpack it, and run:

```
make   
sudo make install
```

Then reboot.

---

Tested on 13.04, 3.10.9-031009-generic kernel, h/w Model: Pavilion 15-E016Tx
  product: RT3290 Bluetooth, vendor: Ralink corp

Comment: Thanks mahesh! I had same problem on 12.04 and your solution worked like a charm! bluetooth working perfectly fine now! thanks a lot!

Comment: does not work with ubuntu 14.04 LTS