# RT3290 Bluetooth Not Working

Tags: 13.04, drivers, bluetooth, ralink

I have an HP Envy H8-1437c system and my bluetooth is not working. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 with `kubuntu-desktop` installed. This is a UEFI system, but legacy boot is turned on.

I have a Ralink RT3290 wireless and bluetooth card, and the wireless works fine. When I go to the bluetooth settings in KDE, I am told that no bluetooth adapters were found.

Here is one part of the output of `lspci -v`:

> 03:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
>         Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 18ec
>         Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
>         Memory at f7200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
>         Capabilities:

And `rfkill list`:

> 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
>
> ```
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no
> ```

As you can see, bluetooth simply does not show up. I know that my computer is capable of using bluetooth; it worked before I wiped Windows and it is clearly advertised on the box that the computer came in.

I tried downloading the driver for the bluetooth card from http://downloads.zotac.com/mediadrivers/mb/download/NB087_Ubuntu.zip. When I follow the instructions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324115/ralink-bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04), I get stuck at the first step. Here is the output of the `make` command when I am in `~/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3`:

> make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build M=/home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3 modules
>   make(1): Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
>     CC [M]  /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.o
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:38:44: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__devinitdata’
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c: In function ‘rtbt_pci_suspend’:
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:60:43: error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘driver_data’
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c: In function ‘rtbt_pci_resume’:
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:87:46: error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘driver_data’
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c: At top level:
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:101:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtbt_pci_probe’
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:228:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtbt_pci_remove’
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:288:14: error: ‘rtbt_pci_ids’ undeclared here (not in a function)
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:290:11: error: ‘rtbt_pci_probe’ undeclared here (not in a function)
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:292:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__devexit_p’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:292:24: error: ‘rtbt_pci_remove’ undeclared here (not in a function)
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c: In function ‘BthIsr’:
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:346:40: error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘driver_data’
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c: At top level:
>   /home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.c:42:1: error: ‘__mod_pci_device_table’ aliased to undefined symbol ‘rtbt_pci_ids’
>   cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
>   make[2]: *** [/home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_core_pci.o] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ashwin/Downloads/rtbth_v3.9.3/rtbth_v3.9.3] Error 2
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

I do not know why I cannot build the package. Based on other people's reports, the driver works once you build it. I need the `rtbth.ko` file to put into `/etc/Wireless/RT3290`. Please help me get my bluetooth working... Thanks!

**Edit:** I just read another AskUbuntu post about this, with the same problem as me. Please see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285163/ralink-rt3290-cant-be-installed). I am wondering if I can somehow download the `rtbth.ko` file from somewhere, since that is really all I need to get bluetooth working... I appreciate any help on this topic. I know I could switch back to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but I really can't because there is software on Ubuntu 13.04 that I need for work... Thanks again!

Comment: Hi! Are you still used 13.04 or you migrated to 13.10? There is some steps need to be completed before make rtbth.ko module. Some configs need to be edited. I need to know this information if you still need Bluetooth working on Ubuntu 13.xx

Comment: One question also. Have you tried run `make` from root? I looking into your comments and didn't see hot it was executed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fix to this problem which I will explain here ([source](http://wirama.web.id/rt3290-bluetooth-rtbth-driver-with-kernel-3-13/))

modify `rtbth_core_bluez.c` line 406 and just comment out this line.

```
//hdev->ioctl = rtbt_hci_dev_ioctl;
```

then change `rtbth_core_bluez.c` line #216 and comment out the original line, replacing it with:

```
//status = hci_recv_frame(skb);
status = hci_recv_frame(hdev, skb);
```

after that, you need to change `rtbth_core_bluez.c` in line 86 and make these changes (is it clear?)

```
//int rtbt_hci_dev_send(struct sk_buff *skb)
int rtbt_hci_dev_send(struct hci_dev *hdev, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
        //struct hci_dev *hdev = (struct hci_dev *)skb->dev;
```

after making these changes you should be able to compile and add your BT devices, although I never managed to add a device myself.

by the way, the patch provided inside the link does not work and you have to do this by yourself.