# Ubuntu 13.10: No Bluetooth adapters found

Tags: bluetooth

My notebook is Fujitsu LH532 with Bluetooth version 4.0 (smart ready).  I have dual boot of Windows 8  and Ubuntu 13.10.  The Bluetooth work fine in Windows 8 but it cannot be found in Ubuntu 13.10.

I didn't find the solution from askubuntu and therefore I post the problem to here again.  I think it could be the problem of new bluetooth driver?

Comment: Your question is similar to [this][1] i think.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/324115/ralink-bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04/375157

Answer (score 2):

I installed the Bluetooth Manager from Ubuntu Software Center and it detected the HP X4000b mouse I am using and I selected to trust the device and the I clicked the create pairing button and it works.