# RT3290 Bluetooth not pairing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bluetooth

I recently followed the instructions listed in the following link to get my `RT3290` bluetooth working on my laptop. These instructions have yielded the most progress I have had in the year I have had this laptop. My machine now sees my bluetooth, I can scan for and see devices, and other devices and see my laptop, but pairing continually fails.

[Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04)

`lscpi` reads

```
04:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

`rfkill list` reads

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg | grep Blue` reads

```
[    5.965811] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[    5.965833] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.965840] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.965842] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.965847] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.038085] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.038088] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.038096] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.058013] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.058024] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.058029] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Any one have any thoughts or ideas I could try? Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @KarlRichter: According to the question, OP is aware of that question and it didn't help them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a known bug for an unsupported device.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there isn't driver for the bluetooth of the RT3290... I have the same problem.
However, if you have a launchpad account you can mark this bug as affecting you:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1189721