# ralink bluetooth now works but will not pair

Tags: bluetooth, ralink

Following these questions:
[Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04)
[RT3290 Bluetooth not pairing in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460753/rt3290-bluetooth-not-pairing-in-ubuntu-14-04)
has lead to a Bluetooth driver that works, except it will not pair. It will recognize and attempt to pair with my Samsung cellphone, a Google Nexus 10 tablet, and a BestBuy tv soundbar. But every pairing attempt results in "Incorrect PIN or password".

The response by David Foerster on Mar 25 at 23:06, "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a known bug for an unsupported device."
gives aid and comfort to those who still claim that civilians should avoid Linux because it requires recompiling device drivers. A device used in this many commercial products should be supported. You may stop reading if you disagree.

One poster listed three dozen machines using the RT3290 chip. (Over 10^5 units shipped, I would guess??)

My question is whether the community wants to leave this device as an impediment to Linux adoption, or whether someone will help me debug the pairing problem.

I will post or share all the details of my ASUS laptop and software if anyone wants to help, but uname -a =
    Linux pascal 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

---edit--
Sorry I forgot to link the bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1189721
Yes, I subscribed to it months ago.

Comment: Failing to link to the original question you reference makes it impossible (even for those who would like to) to vote to re-open your question. The way to deal with the unreferenced known bug is to visit the bug and chime in that this affects you as well, so that the developers understand the urgency. I hope this information helps you help the community to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The device driver is working with devices with older bluetooth V2. I guess the problem is somehow related to the automatic pairing process with newer V3 or V4 devices which are using it. However with an old v2 device i was able to pair and send and receive files using blueman utility and my rt3290le bluetooth wifi combo card. The hcitool command line tool is incorrectly reporting v2.1 bluetooth version and lspci reports it is rt3290le card, which is bluetooth version 4.