# Ralink rt3290 Bluetooth not working

Tags: 12.04, drivers, bluetooth

I was trying to install Ralink rt3290 bluetooth driver which I downloaded from http://s3.amazonaws.com/mtk.cfs/Downloads/linux/-2012_0508_RT3290_Linux_STA_v2.6.0.0.bz2

When I run the make command I get the following error:-

make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
I have 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed.

Answer (score 1):

That does not have the bluetooth drivers yet, only the wireless drivers are working (Barely working. See the link about it). This still has some bugs that need to be worked on as mentioned in this [Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1189721).

For the installation of that specific driver you can look at [How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) especially the part about renaming the file and editing some config files.

For the actual bluetooth there are 2 ways:

**Wirama Web Solution**

The following site did an extensive work on how to [solve this issue](http://wirama.web.id/rt3290-bluetooth-rtbth-driver-with-kernel-3-13/), which points to a PATCH at the end in [github](https://gist.github.com/initrunlevel0/11025774). There is also a question regarding this issue in [Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04)

**Updating Kernel**

You can also (This is risky and can have a lot of issues) update to the 3.15 or 3.16 Kernel. This 2 versions come with many bluetooth updates.

I would recommend the Wirama Solution until a proper solution can be found.

Comment: I followed the link provided but I am getting the same error mentioned above "ERROR 2" not able compile

Comment: I recommend in the meantime to follow the bug report and report the error you are getting there while this driver is worked one. For what I can see, you have several options apart from the one you are doing. You can also follow up on the comments in the Wirama site.