# Bluetooth Driver for Realtek RT3290

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, realtek

I see so many people are looking for the Bluetooth driver for RT3290 from realtek. But there is same hardware qualified(under certified systems) by Ubuntu with same Chip e.g. "Ubuntu on Asus X501U" ; so why can't the same driver be accessible for others using standard ubuntu releases in different systems ? Am I missing something ? - Rgds,

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04 unless you specify which version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

That bluetooth device needs a proprietary driver due to its design and it doesn't seem that Ralink wants to release it to the kernel developers
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-trusty/+bug/1355096