# No Bluetooth Adapter Found in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, 16.04, adapter

I am using HP Pavilion G6 laptop. And I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and before that I was using Ubuntu 14.04. But I can't use my Bluetooth as there is no adapter present.
Output of rfkill and lspci is attached.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Driver for Realtek RT3290](http://askubuntu.com/questions/564579/bluetooth-driver-for-realtek-rt3290) unfortunately the status hasn't changed.  Some have got close but there always seems to be issues

Comment: Yes, I went through that solution way back but it didn't work.