# Ralink RT3290 Bluetooth drivers (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, bluetooth, ralink

So, has anybody gotten the RA3290 Bluetooth adapter working [for 14.04]?  I've seen plenty of posts here, and tried all of them, and nothing works.

Interestingly enough, I had the damn thing working by following directions here:

[Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04)

But at some point, it broke on my 14.04 system and wouldn't recompile.  I've since upgraded to 14.10, and I'm wondering if there has been any progress on this front.

Thanks in advance,

Russo

Comment: Read my answer.