# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - RT3290 - WIFI Working, Bluetooth Not Working

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I have this HP Compaq 15-s008TU Laptop. I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

My WIFI is working fine and after logging in, I installed updates over WIFI.

For Bluetooth it says, Bluetooth Adapter not found.

I am using linux after some 6 Years, so not up to date with current environment status.

For last three days, I have followed all the threads online to get BT working but to no avail.

Do we have a RT3290 BT Driver compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Help please!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04  It may or may not work, the poster claimed it originally worked but quit

Comment: Thanks Jeremy31. I have already tried procedure in this thread. But it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Blueman and audio control from the store.

Those will help to scan, pair, connect headset and audio sink set up bluetooth and you can connect.