# Cannot turn Bluetooth on on my Ubuntu 14.04 system

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

My hardware has support for Bluetooth, but every time I need to use Bluetooth I have no option but to boot to Windows. I have tried many options, but most of them have failed to provide any solution. The basic problem is that I cannot turn the adapter on at all. This is what I get on the System Settings window: [image: http://i59.tinypic.com/oigmt5.png]

As you can see, the Bluetooth and Visibility switches are frozen. I haven't yet found a way to remedy this. Ideas?

Comment: what's your chip number/model ? use this command  and send me the result
`lspci |grep Bluetooth`

Comment: @AliRezaMosajjal `01:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I have the same problem... :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I follow the answer of [Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04) question, and luckly it solved the problem I had. I already modified the files that needed to be modified. You can download the file form http://www.filedropper.com/rtbth-393. All you have to do is go to the directory from terminal and run

```
make
sudo make install
```

And then reboot your computer. I attached a screen shot. It worked for me, hope it work for you too. Good luck.

[image]

Comment: Are you being able to pair devices now?

Comment: no. Pairing is not working for me.. :(

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried reinstall bluetooth, and enter this in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install blueman
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: I am afraid I have tried that before, but to no avail.