# Ralink RT3290 bluetooth no blocked, not work

Tags: drivers, 15.04, laptop, bluetooth, ralink

I follow this guide [Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04) and when I type `rfkill list all` =

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

3: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

but bluetooth is still now working, I can enable it, but it is still saying bluetooth disabled and LED on laptop is still orange (HP)