# Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I have wifi and Bluetooth modules RT3290. Wifi is working fine but Bluetooth is shown as disabled under Bluetooth settings. Can anyone help me fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is a longstanding, ongoing bug about this card, affecting a lot of users, in different ways. [Here is the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bluetooth/+bug/1189721). We might need to wait until a complete fix is released.

Answer (score 4):

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (Kernel 4.8)

1. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
   ```
2. Download zip from [here on GitHub](https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms.git) and unzip it to Desktop.
3. Change your directory to new unzipped directory (i.e. `~/Desktop/rtbth-dkms-master`).
4. Run the following commands one by one

   ```
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo cp -r ~/Desktop/rtbth-dkms-master /usr/src/rtbth-3.9.3
   sudo dkms install rtbth/3.9.3
   sudo nano /etc/modules
   ```
5. Add `rtbth` at the end, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (to save the file) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to close the editor
6. Reboot

Ref : *https://askubuntu.com/a/828925/703994* ; *https://askubuntu.com/a/904222/703994*

Comment: Actually it should be "sudo chmod +x *",  means all files.

Comment: Most of the files were C files so I was kind of skeptical about it. Agree with you and I would appreciate if you could advise on the same.

Comment: I tried this way but didn't work for me.  Using above approach although I am not able to pair my devices but at least I can see a bluetooth icon on my staus bar.

Comment: Worked for ubuntu 19.04 too.

Answer (score 0):

It is a supported card for bluetooth http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/pci/1814%3A3298/

There is a to getting it working with bluetooth here
[Ralink Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324115/ralink-bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04)

The second answer shows how to compile it yourself which you will need to do if the modules in the archive don't load because the kernel has changed since they where built

Answer (score 0):

A fix that was reported to work is from a github site, to install

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/f1u77y/rtbth.git
cd rtbth
make 
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't work

Comment: I would uninstall it then with `cd rtbth && sudo make uninstall`