# Error on installing RT3290 bluetooth driver Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, compiling, ralink

Hi guys I am Ubuntu beginner and I faced a problem with bluetooth device.
My laptop is HP Pavilion G6 2316sx and my blutooth model is RT3290. Ubuntu 16.10

Note: my wifi is working but bluetooth does not.
I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/alinefr/rtbth.git
cd rtbth
make 
sudo make install
```

But I got this error when ran `make`:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/build M=/home/ahmed/Desktop/tmp/rtbth modules make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic'   
CC [M]  /home/ahmed/Desktop/tmp/rtbth/rtbth_core_bluez.o /home/ahmed/Desktop/tmp/rtbth/rtbth_core_bluez.c: In function ‘rtbt_hps_iface_init’: /home/ahmed/Desktop/tmp/rtbth/rtbth_core_bluez.c:381:22: error: ‘HCI_BREDR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     hdev->dev_type = HCI_BREDR;
                      ^~~~~~~~~ /home/ahmed/Desktop/tmp/rtbth/rtbth_core_bluez.c:381:22: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/home/ahmed/Desktop/tmp/rtbth/rtbth_core_bluez.o' 
failed make[2]: *** [/home/ahmed/Desktop/tmp/rtbth/rtbth_core_bluez.o] Error 1 Makefile:1489: recipe for target '_module_/home/ahmed/Desktop/tmp/rtbth' 
failed make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ahmed/Desktop/tmp/rtbth] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic' Makefile:24: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I followed this topic
[Ralink Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324115/ralink-bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04)
but again got the same error on the same command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ralink RT 3290 Bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 14.04](/q/453605/175814)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](http://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290)

Comment: i tried both of them and i got the same error . note that my wifi driver is working but bluetooth does not.